# Issues serving Jekyll to localhost, eventmachine 1.2.7 has an error when installing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundle, eventmachine

Not sure what to do to specifically fix this problem, googled and nothing solved my question.  When I try to:

`bundle exec jekyll serve`

I get told:

```
Could not find eventmachine-1.2.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Then I:

`bundle install`

Only to get this:

```
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /private/var/folders/7f/2c2swwc1153899dmr8781_x40000gn/T/bundler20201130-34411-1lzt2fceventmachine-1.2.7/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20201130-34411-pd54nh.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/7f/2c2swwc1153899dmr8781_x40000gn/T/bundler20201130-34411-1lzt2fceventmachine-1.2.7/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/var/folders/7f/2c2swwc1153899dmr8781_x40000gn/T/bundler20201130-34411-1lzt2fceventmachine-1.2.7/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  minima was resolved to 2.5.1, which depends on
    jekyll-feed was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
      jekyll was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
        em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.1, which depends on
          eventmachine
```

Where am I going wrong here?  Just updated to macOS 11.0.1, this is my first time trying to serve jekyll since the update.  Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 17):

Just try:

```
gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

Comment: This didn't work but the following worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74283428/4758119

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on Big Sur and this solution worked perfectly:

[How to fix Jekyll after upgrading to MacOS 11 (Big Sur)](https://ernestojeh.com/fix-jekyll-on-macos-big-sur)

Download XCODE 12 beta [from here](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and copy it to the Applications folder.

Then follow these steps to install **rbenv.**

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

```
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
```

Add `~/.rbenv/bin` to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility. see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout

```
xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Now in your Jekyll project's root, you should be able to run `bundle install` and it should install all missing dependencies and should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to build ruby or install XCode. While Jekyll [requires Ruby 2.4.0](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/#install-ruby) or higher and Big Sur comes with 2.6.3, I [followed Jekyll's instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/#brew) to install the latest version of Ruby.

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install ruby
```

Add Ruby to your shell configuration in .bash_profile.

```sh
PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Install bundler. I had to upgrade to Jekyll 4.2 from 4.0, and install webrick which is [no longer a default gem](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/8523) with Ruby 3.0. If Jekyll is installed globally, then install it, webrick, and any other gems, like jekyll-paginate, too.

```sh
gem install --user-install bundler jekyll
```

Add the gems path to your shell configuration in .bash_profile, replacing X.X with with first two digits of the Ruby version.

```sh
PATH="$HOME/.gem/ruby/X.X.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```