# Cannot install jekyll (eventmachine) on m1 mac

Tags: ruby, arm, rubygems

I'm a real newbie to iOS development and wanna make a new GitHub blog.

I'm following [How to install jekyll on Apple M1 Macbook](https://www.earthinversion.com/blogging/how-to-install-jekyll-on-appple-m1-macbook/) as a reference.

And I've tried installing Jekyll on my M1 Pro Macbook (macOS Monterey 12.6) but it fails when installing Bundler and Jekyll with `gem install --user-install bundler jekyll` (output below).

I already read articles from many bloggers who finally succeeded. How can I solve this problem? Please somebody help me!

```
[eric@~/blog/hyleedevelop.github.io]$ gem install --user-install bundler jekyll
Successfully installed bundler-2.3.24
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.3.24
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/eric/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/Users/eric/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/bin/ruby -I /Users/eric/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20221026-8644-6ak8a4.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lcrypto... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for openssl/err.h... yes
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... yes
checking for pipe2() in unistd.h... no
checking for accept4() in sys/socket.h... no
checking for SOCK_CLOEXEC in sys/socket.h... no
checking for sys/event.h... yes
checking for sys/queue.h... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW in time.h... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
CXXFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-unused-result -Wno-address
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/eric/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/eric/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling binder.cpp
compiling cmain.cpp
compiling ed.cpp
compiling em.cpp
compiling kb.cpp
compiling page.cpp
compiling pipe.cpp
compiling rubymain.cpp
rubymain.cpp:220:3: warning: 'rb_rescue' is deprecated: Use of ANYARGS in this function is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                rb_rescue((VALUE (*)(ANYARGS))event_callback, (VALUE)&e, (VALUE (*)(ANYARGS))event_error_handler, Qnil);
                ^
/Users/eric/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/cxxanyargs.hpp:244:1: note: 'rb_rescue' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED("Use of ANYARGS in this function is deprecated")
^
/Users/eric/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/backward/2/attributes.h:79:35: note: expanded from macro 'RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED'
#define RUBY_CXX_DEPRECATED(mseg) RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED((mseg))
                                  ^
/Users/eric/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/internal/attr/deprecated.h:32:53: note: expanded from macro 'RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED'
# define RBIMPL_ATTR_DEPRECATED(msg) __attribute__((__deprecated__ msg))
                                                    ^
1 warning generated.
compiling ssl.cpp
linking shared-object rubyeventmachine.bundle
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_BIO_ctrl", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::CanGetCiphertext() in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::PutPlaintext(char const*, int) in ssl.o
  "_BIO_free", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_BIO_new", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_BIO_new_file", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_BIO_new_mem_buf", referenced from:
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
  "_BIO_read", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetCiphertext(char*, int) in ssl.o
  "_BIO_s_mem", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_BIO_write", referenced from:
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::PutCiphertext(char const*, int) in ssl.o
  "_DH_free", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_EC_KEY_free", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_ERR_print_errors_fp", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
  "_EVP_PKEY_free", referenced from:
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
      SslContext_t::~SslContext_t() in ssl.o
  "_OBJ_sn2nid", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_OPENSSL_init_crypto", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_OPENSSL_init_ssl", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_PEM_read_bio_DHparams", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey", referenced from:
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
  "_PEM_read_bio_X509", referenced from:
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
  "_PEM_write_bio_X509", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CIPHER_get_bits", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetCipherBits() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CIPHER_get_name", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetCipherName() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CIPHER_get_version", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetCipherProtocol() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_ctrl", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_free", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::~SslContext_t() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_new", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_set_options", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_certificate", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_accept", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_clear", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::~SslBox_t() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_connect", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_ctrl", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_free", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::~SslBox_t() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_current_cipher", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetCipherBits() in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::GetCipherName() in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::GetCipherProtocol() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_error", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::PutPlaintext(char const*, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_ex_data", referenced from:
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_ex_data_X509_STORE_CTX_idx", referenced from:
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_peer_certificate", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPeerCert() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_servername", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetSNIHostname() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_get_shutdown", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::~SslBox_t() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_is_init_finished", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
      SslBox_t::PutPlaintext(char const*, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_new", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_read", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::GetPlaintext(char*, int) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_set_bio", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_set_ex_data", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_set_verify", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::SslBox_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, unsigned long) in ssl.o
  "_SSL_shutdown", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::~SslBox_t() in ssl.o
  "_SSL_write", referenced from:
      SslBox_t::PutPlaintext(char const*, int) in ssl.o
  "_TLS_client_method", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_TLS_server_method", referenced from:
      SslContext_t::SslContext_t(bool, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) in ssl.o
  "_X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert", referenced from:
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_X509_STORE_CTX_get_ex_data", referenced from:
      _ssl_verify_wrapper in ssl.o
  "_X509_free", referenced from:
      t_get_peer_cert(unsigned long, unsigned long) in rubymain.o
      InitializeDefaultCredentials() in ssl.o
      SslContext_t::~SslContext_t() in ssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rubyeventmachine.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/eric/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/eric/.gem/ruby/3.0.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.0.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
1 gem installed
```

Comment: I would try to install the eventmachine gem first (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68730953/install-gem-eventmachine-1-2-7-with-ssl-on-m1) and then try bundle install again.

Comment: I am using an M1 with Ruby 3.1.2 witout errors, Your undefined symbols errors all relate to SSL (ssl.o). Mabye your missing openssl. Don't forget to install openssl first, e.g. by running `brew install openssl`. Here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818391/gem-eventmachine-fatal-error-openssl-ssl-h-file-not-found. It depends on how you have installed openssl.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

```
gem install eventmachine -- --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
```

Comment: I didn't have `openssl` at that location, probably because I installed it via home-brew. I was able to get this to work with `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)`.

Comment: (obviously change the 1.2.7 bit to whatever version you need)

Comment: `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' -- --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix libressl)` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on my mac (intel, macos ventura,13.2.1).

There are two rubys on my computer, one installed via homebrew and one that comes with the system.
First use `which ruby` to view the location of ruby
and use `brew --prefix ruby` can see where homebrew is installed our ruby.
Add this at the end of your ~/.zshrc file. I recommend to use ruby installed by homebrew, which is easier to upgrade.

On Mac Intel:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

On Apple silicon:

```
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

load the config with command:

`source ~/.zshrc`

then continue to run:
`bundle install`

Now everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

The Open SSL answer didn't fix it for me, it ended up being that I hadn't accepted the xCode license. This was specific to Mac OS Ventura, 2023

`sudo xcodebuild -license accept`

After running that, I could run `bundle` without issue

I do want to note that my error was different from OP:

```
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.2.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.2.7' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages uses ruby 2.7.4

https://pages.github.com/versions

However, you'd need to use a slightly newer version to build it on M1.

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

cd <project>
rbenv install 2.7.8
rbenv local 2.7.8
bundle install

bundle exec jekyll serve
```

References:

https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv